# Registering NLog as logger for non specific host in dot net core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nlog

I have non web generic host application, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1 I should add logger in .ConfigureLogging but

- ConfigureLogging has different prototype for me than it has in docs, ILoggingBuilder doesnt't have for example `.ClearProviders()`
- I can't use `.AddNlog()` for DI as shown [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3)

```
      .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
      {
          logging.ClearProviders();
          logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
      })
      .UseNLog();  // NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection
```

I think my confusion is caused by not building a web application whereas guides specify configuring NLog for asp.net. Why is NLog different package for web application? Is this caused by NLog automatically logging events released by Kestrel or other web-specific stuff? What's the difference between UseNLog method (which is an extension defined by NLog I presume?) and registering NLog in services as singleton

Comment: I have a similar use case with almost identical code. The code you have should work assuming you have the right package references. `.UseNLog()` resolves to the method `public static IHostBuilder UseNLog(this IHostBuilder builder)` in the `NLog.Web.AspNetCore` package, so despite the name of the package, there is no dependency on this being a web host. The `.ClearProviders()` method comes from the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` package.

Comment: You can also add the package NLog.Extensions.Hosting which has the extension method of UseNLog()

Answer (score 3):

Both `AddNLog()` and `ClearProviders()` are extensions methods. You need to add using namespace along with the relevant nuget-packages.

```
using NLog.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
```

And add these nuget-packages to your project:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging
- ASP.NET Core: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore/ (using NLog.Web)

There are also wiki-pages and examples to be found:

- https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/blob/master/examples/NetCore2/HostingExample/Program.cs
- https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-.NET-Core-2---Console-application
- https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3